# Linq Queryable Expression Tree: SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '&'

Tags: linq, tree, expression

I am getting an error: { SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '&' } which I cannot seem to figure out. I have a class QuestionResult (seen below).

```
public class QuestionResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float? Result { get; set; }
    public string ResultText { get; set; }

    //Foreign Keys & Connections
    public virtual SurveyResult SurveyResult { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int SurveyResultId { get; set; }
}
```

which I wish to filter by QuestionId & Result, for example {QuestionId == 48 && Result >= 24}. The issue appears to be around using Expression.And. I tried this test without using it, using just one of the conditions and it ran fine. I have previously used Expression.And and it has worked.

```
public static List<int> GetIdList()
{ 
    IQueryable<QuestionResult> questionResultList = _context.QuestionResult.AsQueryable();
    var questionResult = Expression.Parameter(typeof(QuestionResult), "qr");
    MemberExpression questionId = Expression.Property(questionResult, "QuestionId");
    MemberExpression result = Expression.Property(questionResult, "Result");
    var conditionA = Expression.Equal(questionId, Expression.Constant(48));
    var conditionB = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(result, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(24), result.Type));
    var and = Expression.And(conditionA, conditionB);
    var predicateBody = Expression.Lambda<Func<QuestionResult, bool>>(and, questionResult);

    MethodCallExpression query = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { questionResultList.ElementType },
        questionResultList.Expression,
        predicateBody
    );
    var questionResultIdList = questionResultList.Provider.CreateQuery<QuestionResult>(query).Select(i => i.Id).ToList();

    return questionResultIdList;
}
```

Can you see somewhere that I have gone wrong with this? Debugging the query before it has run shows:

{value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[SurveyV3.Models.DatabaseModels.QuestionResult]).Where(qr => ((qr.QuestionId == 48) And (qr.Result >= Convert(24))))}

which looks right to me. I have been using questions on here and this Microsoft page for assistance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

Thanks, Oj

Comment: Not sure this is the solution, but I would use `Expression.AndAlso` (logical comparison) instead of `Expression.And` (bitwise comparison). I don't think EF appreciates bitwise comparison.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that was the issue.

Comment: Why are you manually creating an expression tree to do this?  The IQueryable API is there exactly for this purpose, so you can avoid manually creating expression trees.  I'd strongly recommend against this approach unless you absolutely have to, as it really harms the maintainability of the code.

Comment: This was just a dumbed down example to replicate my error. My implemented version will be doing a lot more dynamic functions such as using all numeric operators and some string actions all inside a loop so there will be many expressions like ((qr.QuestionId == 48) And (qr.Result >= Convert(24))) grouped together inside the end query.

Answer (score 0):

> > var and = Expression.And(conditionA, conditionB);

`Expression.And` does a *bitwise* AND operation.

You want `Expression.AndAlso` which does a logical AND.